# Rails 4 custom helper method with form doesn't get output in view - fully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view-helpers

I have this in `application_helper.rb` because I use the same filter form for a number of models.

```
def filter_form(path, filter_options, button)
    form_tag(path, remote: true, method: "get") do 
      label_tag(:filter, "Filter by")
      select_tag(:filter_type, options_for_select(filter_options))
      "<span>for:</span>".html_safe
      text_field_tag(:filter)
      button_tag(:submit, "Submit") if button == true
    end
  end
```

And in my user articles for example I have

```
<%= filter_form(articles_path, @filter_options, false) %>
```

However in the code I can see it only generates the `<form action="/articles" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="get"><input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden"></form>` tag which is all fine and good but none of the form elements show up. Why is that?

Comment: You need use `concat`

Comment: Where? Like on every line at the end or where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [***`concat`***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat)

```
def filter_form(path, filter_options, button)
   form_tag(path, remote: true, method: "get") do 
     concat label_tag(:filter, "Filter by")
     concat select_tag(:filter_type, options_for_select(filter_options))
     "<span>for:</span>".html_safe
     concat text_field_tag(:filter)
     concat button_tag(:submit, "Submit") if button == true
   end
end
```

There is a good article [***here***](http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/)