# Rails generate HTML in custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following simplified helper which works:

```
module MyHelper
  def widget
    link_to new_flag_path do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-flag")
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to output a second link such as:

```
  module MyHelper
    def widget
      link_to new_flag_path do
        content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-flag")
      end
      link_to new_comment_path do
        content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-comment")
      end
    end
  end
```

The solution outlined in the pugautomatic article uses "concat" to concatenate multiple helpers within a single block helper. http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/ This works for standard link_to helpers such as:

```
module MyHelper
  def widget
    concat link_to("Hello", hello_path)
    concat " "
    concat link_to("Bye", goodbye_path)
  end
end
```

When using a glyphon in a href you need to use a link_to block helper such as:

```
link_to new_comment_path do
  content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-comment")
end
```

Concat does not allow me to concat multiple link_to block helpers such as:

```
module MyHelper
  def widget
    concat link_to new_flag_path do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-flag")
    end
    concat link_to new_comment_path do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-comment")
    end
  end
end
```

What is the solution in this scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 custom helper method with form doesn't get output in view - fully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682206/rails-4-custom-helper-method-with-form-doesnt-get-output-in-view-fully)

Comment: I am familiar with the solution in the linked article however it does now work in this scenario. Concat can only be used within the link_to and accordingly does not allow multiple link_to helpers to be chained.

Comment: fontawesome-sass is giving you `icon(:flag)`. just sayin

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to put each link_to to separate method:

```
module MyHelper
  def link_to_flag_page
    link_to new_flag_path do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-flag")
    end
  end

  def link_to_new_comment
    link_to new_comment_path do
      content_tag(:i, '', class: "fa fa-comment")
    end
  end
end
```

And call them one by one

Comment: The example above is a simplified version of a helper with much logic that needs to output two links from the one helper method.

Comment: But what you showed is not a helper method, it's just a module. Can you encapsulate this logic into a method, then call it from the view?